# Counting character in a 1 line huge file

Tags: shell, file, count, bigdata

I'm working with a huge file (4 GB). This file doesn't have conventional line delimiter. Instead of the \n or such, the line delimiter is a bunch of characters (#@#@#).

On this annoying file, I would like to count the number of time the "#@#@#" string occurs to get the number of line.

I tried:

```
grep -o "#@#@#" MyHugeFile.txt | wc -l

awk -F'#@#@#' '{print NF-1}' MyHugeFile.txt

awk '{print gsub(/#@#@#/,"&")}' MyHugeFile.txt
```

But none of them would work: the process seems to die before it gets the number of occurrence.

Is there another way ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: How about trying like: `awk '{print gsub(/#@#@#/,"&")}' Input_file` once? Fair warning I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried but it run for ages and do not give an answer (it"s running for an hour already).

Comment: I am pretty sure you have very low memory settings in your system, correct? It worked for me for 4 GB a test file and it was cool for me.

Comment: May be it's that memory settings very low indeed...